# Scrapy: how to catch download error and try download it again

Tags: python, scrapy

During my crawling, some pages failed due to unexpected redirection and no response returned. How can I catch this kind of error and re-schedule a request with original url, not with the redirected url?

Before I ask here, I do a lot of search with Google. Looks there's two ways to fix this issue. one is catch exception in a download middle-ware, the other is to process download exception in errback in spider's request. For these two questions, I have some questions.

- For method 1, I don't know how to pass the original url to process_exception function. Below is the example code I have tried.

> ```
> class ProxyMiddleware(object):
>
>     def process_request(self, request, spider):
>         request.meta['proxy'] = "http://192.168.10.10"
>         log.msg('>>>> Proxy %s'%(request.meta['proxy'] if request.meta['proxy'] else ""), level=log.DEBUG)
>     def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
>         log_msg('Failed to request url %s with proxy %s with exception %s' % (request.url, proxy if proxy else 'nil', str(exception)))
>         #retry again.
>         return request
> ```

- For method 2, I don't know how to pass external parameter to errback function in the spider. I don't know how to retrieve original url from this errback function to re-schedule a request.

  Below is the example I tried with method 2:

> ```
> class ProxytestSpider(Spider):
>
>     name = "proxytest"
>     allowed_domains = ["baidu.com"]
>     start_urls = (
>         'http://www.baidu.com/',
>         )
>     def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
>         starturl = url
>         request = Request(url, dont_filter=True,callback = self.parse, errback = self.download_errback)
>         print "make requests"
>         return request
>     def parse(self, response):
>         pass
>         print "in parse function"        
>     def download_errback(self, e):
>         print type(e), repr(e)
>         print repr(e.value)
>         print "in downloaderror_callback"
> ```

Any suggestion for this recrawl issue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Bing

Comment: @dabling1205, show us what you've tried

Comment: The post looks a litter messy, I am new to here and not familiar with the edit format, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a lambda as an errback:

```
request = Request(url, dont_filter=True,callback = self.parse, errback = lambda x: self.download_errback(x, url))
```

that way you'll have access to the url inside the errback function:

```
def download_errback(self, e, url):
    print url
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the RETRY_HTTP_CODES in settings.py

This is the settings I use for proxy errors:

```
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]
```

Comment: mates, Thanks for your answer. Your comments works well in the case of when download has response returned with a status.:), not for the download error happens.

Comment: thanks for commenting @dabing1205 . Would you mind sharing the case where you encounter error or the type of Exception ?