# Making a spider restarable

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

My intention is to scrape a few urls using a spider such as follows:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ContentsPageSFBItem

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "contentspage_sfb"
    #allowed_domains = ["web"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/shell-programming-in/9780134496696/',
        'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cisa-certified-information/9780134677453/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            item = ContentsPageSFBItem()

            #from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
            #inspect_response(response, self)

            content_items = response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//a/text()').extract()

            for content_item in content_items:

                item['content_item'] = content_item
                item["full_url"] = response.url
                item['title'] = response.xpath('//title[1]/text()').extract()

                yield item
```

I intend to use more urls. My intention is to create a restartable spider incase something goes wrong. My plan is to add exceptions and create a csv with the list of remaining urls. Where exactly can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the current url in which has occurred such problem and then pass it in an `scrapy.Request` using the same `parse` function to continue.

You can see if something has been printed in the website being visited using the `response.body`, is something bad has happened then `yield` a new `scrapy.Request` if isn't then continue as normal.

Maybe:

```
def parse(self, response):
    current_url = response.request.url
    if 'Some or none message in the body' in response.body:
        yield scrapy.Request(current_url, callback=self.parse)
    else:
        item = ContentsPageSFBItem()
        content_items = response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//a/text()').extract()

        for content_item in content_items:
            item['content_item'] = content_item
            item['full_url']     = response.url
            item['title']        = response.xpath('//title[1]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Note that the way you use again the `parse` function depends heavily on which "exception" you want to catch.

Keeping in mind you want to write the data to different files, depending on the url you're, then I've tweaked a little bit the code:

For first creating three global variables to store the first and second url, and the fields as an array. Nnote this would be useful for those 2 urls but if they start growing that would be difficult:

```
global first_url, second_url, fields
fields = []
first_url = 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/shell-programming-in/9780134496696/'
second_url = 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cisa-certified-information/9780134677453/'
start_urls = [first_url, second_url]
```

Then within your `parse` function you get the data and store it in the `fields` array, which will be passed to a second function `parse_and_write_csv`, to create and write on every file depending on the current url.

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = ContentsPageSFBItem()
    content_items = response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//a/text()').extract()
    url = response.request.url

    for content_item in content_items:

        item['content_item'] = content_item
        item['full_url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title[1]/text()').extract()

        fields = [item['content_item'].encode('utf-8'), item['full_url'], item['title'][0]]

        self.parse_and_write_csv(response, fields)
```

The `parse_and_write_csv` get the fields and depending on the url it gets the 5th element from an array created from the url and creates a csv file or opens it if it already exists.

```
def parse_and_write_csv(self, response, fields):
    with open("%s.csv" % response.request.url.split('/')[5], 'a+') as file:
        file.write("{}\n".format(';'.join(str(field) 
                                      for field in fields)))
```

Hope it helps. You can see a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/942218e1ed1aa084bb5ac8f757ce6fa6) here.

Comment: I want to know how to create a separate csv for each url. Also I want to skip iterations for any exception. But which file should I modify for this?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce what you try to achieve, is it something like that?

Comment: Do you mean as `start_urls`?

Comment: yes. the github version works perfectly. I can create separate csv files. Is there way to create an additional csv file with urls so that if there is a break the remaning will be stored. Naturally it must read it if the file is available

Comment: I think you could use the `errback` callback and use a function to perform what you need when an error occurrs. You could see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24572269/5025116) short answer as reference.

Comment: Thanks. Would this work on something like keyboard interrupt?

Comment: I think yes, you could make use of the `scrapy.signals`, specifically the [`spider_closed`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed).